# Difference between Dense and Activation layer in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I was wondering what was the difference between Activation Layer and Dense layer in Keras.

Since Activation Layer seems to be a fully connected layer, and Dense have a parameter to pass an activation function, what is the best practice ?

Let's imagine a fictionnal network like this :
Input -> Dense -> Dropout -> Final Layer
Final Layer should be : Dense(activation=softmax) or Activation(softmax) ?
What is the cleanest and why ?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Using `Dense(activation=softmax)` is computationally equivalent to first add `Dense` and then add `Activation(softmax)`. However there is one advantage of the second approach - you could retrieve the outputs of the last layer (before activation) out of such defined model. In the first approach - it's impossible.

Comment: can you spot any advantages of using the first one?

Comment: Model definition is shorter and more compact.

Comment: So in Keras if I have to fine tune an InceptionV3 network on 20 classes, do I take the base_model.output where the base_model is InceptionV3(), and then add a Dense(1024, activation+"relu")(base_model.output followed by Dense(20, activation='softmax')? Is this the right way to do it in Keras?

Comment: yes from the Keras documentation (https://keras.io/activations/), it is equivalent

Answer (score 1):

As @MarcinMożejko said, it is equivalent. I just want to explain why. If you look at the `Dense` [Keras documentation page](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/), you'll see that the default activation function is `None`.

A dense layer mathematically is:

```
a = g(W.T*a_prev+b)
```

where `g` an activation function. When using `Dense(units=k, activation=softmax)`, it is computing all the quantities in one shot. When doing `Dense(units=k)` and then Activation('softmax), it first calculates the quantity, `W.T*a_prev+b` (because the default activation function is `None`) and then applying the activation function specified as input to the `Activation` layer to the calculated quantity.